# Python list multiplication: [[...]]*3 makes 3 lists which mirror each other when modified

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Why this is happening? I don't really understand:

```
>>> P = [ [()]*3 ]*3
>>> P
[[(), (), ()], [(), (), ()], [(), (), ()]]
>>> P[0][0]=1
>>> P
[[1, (), ()], [1, (), ()], [1, (), ()]]
```

Comment: Why does only the outer `*3` create more references while the inner one doesn't? Why isn't it all `1`s?

Comment: @spelchekr Because when you assign a value, a new object will be created. Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've made 3 references to the same list.

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(42)
>>> b
[42]
```

You want to do this:

```
P = [[()] * 3 for x in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Lists are mutable, and multiplying a list by a number doesn't copy its elements. You can try changing it to a list comprehension, so it will evaluate `[()]*3` three times, creating three different lists:

```
P = [ [()]*3 for i in range(3) ]
```

Comment: This answer needs more attention - "Lists are mutable, and multiplying a list by a number doesn't copy its elements. "

Answer (score 6):

It's actually the same inner list (same reference) that is duplicated 3 times, so when you modify any one of them, you are actually modifying all of them.

So, the inner list `[()]*3` produces a list of three tuples.  But then this list is duplicated three times.  However, in python, it's really a list of references that is being multiplied, so the reference is duplicated, but each reference still points to the same underlying list.

Answer (score 5):

You can also write it like this, which has the advantage of showing the structure `[[()]*3]*3`

```
>>> P=[i[:] for i in [[()]*3]*3]
>>> P[0][0]=1
>>> P
[[1, (), ()], [(), (), ()], [(), (), ()]
```

It's also slightly faster than using range. From ipython shell:

```
In [1]: timeit P = [ [()]*3 for i in range(3) ]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 us per loop

In [2]: timeit P=[i[:] for i in [[()]*3]*3]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 us per loop
```