# creating list with * operator in python

Tags: python, list

Why does `[0] * 5` create a list `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, rather than `[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]`?

Doesn't the `*` operator duplicate `[0]` 5 times resulting in `[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list multiplication: \[\[...\]\]*3 makes 3 lists which mirror each other when modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it multiplies elements and [0] list (just like mathematical set) has one element 0, not [[0]].

Comment: In another word, + means add the elements in the operands into one list, rather than make two lists into elements of a new list?

Answer (score 7):

Just like math:

`[0] * 5 = [0] + [0] + [0] + [0] + [0]`, which is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

I think people would be more surprised if `[0] + [0]` suddenly became `[[0], [0]]`.

For strings, tuples, and lists, `+` is an append operator.  This multiplication holds true for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [Python docs for sequence types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) it seems that it is because `[0] * 5` is shorthand for `[0] + [0] + [0] + [0] + [0]` (just as multiplication is in math a shorthand for addition; it works the same when "multiplying" lists).

Answer (score 0):

Use statement below to create [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]:

```
[[0]*1]*5
```

*Note that the list you've mentioned above is a 2d list, so you must use * operator in right way. It means your list has 5 rows and 1 column.*

Below is the real result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqTWs.jpg)