# Why does 'append' mutates all elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am building a list of lists.  I am reading the elements from an input file. I am reading in each
line in the file as a string-single-element to a sub-list in the list.  First, I created
the list of lists:

```
>>> b = [[]] * 5
```

However, when I tried to append an item, I got the following:

```
>>> b[1].append("abc")
>>> b
[ ['abc'], ['abc'], ['abc'], ['abc'], ['abc'])
```

Why does `append` change all the sub-lists? Is `insert()` better in this situation?

Comment: problem is [[]] * 5 - see what happens with this b = [[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `[[]] * 5` it is a list of same objects (empty lists here) repeated 5 times.

You can check it by:

```
>>> b = [[]] *5

>>> b
[[], [], [], [], []]

>>> id(b[0])
140588316211896

>>> id(b[1])
140588316211896
```

What you would need to do is:

```
>>> b = [[] for i in range(5)]
>>> b[0].append('abc')
>>> b
[['abc'], [], [], [], []]
```

In case of `[[] for i in range(5)]`, in each loop a new empty list object is created.

And insert would not be a good option here because insert is a `O(n)` operation whereas appending would be `O(1)`.

Comment: Could you please explain why your solution works, why in your soultion, the lists are not the same object?

Comment: @idish: Because in every loop a new empty list object is created.

Comment: @ Ankur How do you know insert() is O(n) and append O(1)?

Comment: @Dombey: You can check the time complexity of various python methods here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
b = [[]] * 5
```

It creates 5 lists that all point to the same thing. If you print out the address of each element you'll find that they are the same.

So it wouldn't matter whether you used `append` or `insert`.

Comment: No. Under the hood, the list is primarily composed of 5 references to the same unique list ``[ ]``, it means nothing to say a list points to a "thing" . A thing ? There's a word for that, it's "object".

Comment: @eyquem Yes, it would not be accurate to say it is a list of lists, but I don't really see much of a difference between referring it as some "thing" or some "object".

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ.  All 5 top-level list elements are pointing at the same list.

Check this out:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

if True:
    b = [[] for dummy in range(5)]
else:
    b = [[]] * 5

b[1].append("abc")

print(b)
```