# Incorrect assignment of values in 2D list in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, multidimensional-array

I was trying to assign values to multi dimension list in python after initializing it to zeroes first.
Following is the code where edge_strength and initialProb are multiD list.

```
    edge_strength = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
    initialProb = [[0]*3]*3
    initialColumn =1
    denominator = 10
    for r in range(0,3):
        initialProb[r][initialColumn] = float(edge_strength[r][initialColumn])/denominator
    print initialProb
```

But when I finished and printed initialProb list, I got answer as - [[0, 0.7, 0], [0, 0.7, 0], [0, 0.7, 0]]
Instead it should've been - [[0, 0.2, 0], [0, 0.4, 0], [0, 0.7, 0]].

Can anyone explain me this strange behaviour and the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you solution does not work either. It seems as if edge_strength[r][initialColumn] is broadcasted although initialProb[r][initialColumn] is a scalar. I would expect something similar if you instead wrote

```
initialProb[1] = float(edge_strength[r][initialColumn])/denominator
```

but like this it does not make sense.

Here is a workaround using numpy. numpy-arrays have the advantage, that multiple columns can be addressed at once. I hope that helps at least.

```
import numpy as np
initialProb = np.zeros((3,3))
edge_strength = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
initialProb[:,initialColumn] = edge_strength[:,initialColumn].astype(np.float)/denominator
```

Edit: I understood what's going on. Refer to [Python list multiplication: [[...]]*3 makes 3 lists which mirror each other when modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when) When you initialize initialProb you don't get three different rows, but three references to the same list. If you modify the list, all three are changed.

According to the thread

```
initialProb = [ [0]*3 for r in range(3) ]
```

should also solve your error

Comment: Ohh! The solution to initialize the list [ [0]*3 for r in range(3) ] did solve the problem :). Thanks