# Behavior of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6:

```
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> y = [[]]*2
>>> z = dict(zip(x, y))
>>> z
{0: [], 1: []}
>>> z[0].append(0)
>>> z
{0: [0], 1: [0]}
>>>
```

Why did it append to both?
I tried without zip and it worked fine.
Please explain this behavior

Comment: Short version, `*2` copies the references, doesn't know about calling constructors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when