# Python: pointers to common list object, why does Initializing a 2D matrix with 2 approaches produce different output?

Tags: python

Why are the two outputs different:

The only difference in the 2 approaches is the way the matrix has been initialized. I expect to get the same output in both the scenarios but the output seems to be different?

Is there something I am missing?

```
x = 4
table = [[0]*(x)]*x
for i in range(x):
    table[i][i] = 1
print(table)
```

table: `[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]`

```
x = 4
table = [[0]*x for i in range(x)]
for i in range(x):
    table[i][i] = 1
print(table)
```

table: `[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6688223/11301900.

Comment: Was this question just for learning purposes, or as part of a larger program?

Comment: @AMC it was for learning purpose.
Thanks for providing the links :)

Answer (score 1):

You are having trouble with pointers to a common object.

Consider this (simpler) case:

```
>>> a = list(range(4))
>>> b = a
>>> b[2] = 9
>>> a
[0, 1, 9, 3]
```

Why does changing `b` alter the contents of `a` ?!?
Because they are both names for the *same* mutable object, a `list`.

---

Your second example does what you want.
The list comprehension produces a *new* list object each time you iterate.

Your first example produces a *single* list of length four,
and then produces four pointers to the *same* list.
Changing the list via one of its four names
will produce a change in all four rows of printed output.