# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Abs sens value' and TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, excel

I am creating a data treatment for my thesis. When I print str1 values like **2.802176590012075** come up but I can't convert then to float or use it in operations. Any help in understanding the issue would be deeply appreciated. The excel file has values like **2,802176590012075**.

```
import openpyxl

# Give the location of the file
path = "C:\\Users\\Acer\\.spyder-py3\\output_sens_1660[K]_1.7[atm]_phi=0.5_SORTED_descending_DATA_FILE_Perturbation=0.5_.xlsx"
  
# to open the workbook 
# workbook object is created
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

e=0.55

wb_obj.save(filename="teste.xlsx")
i=0
L=int(len(sheet_obj['D']))
erro=[]*L

for cell in sheet_obj['D']:
    i=i+1
    str1=cell.value
    # changing ',' to '.' 
    def Replace(str1):
        maketrans = str1.maketrans
        final = str1[i].translate(maketrans(',.', '.,', ' '))
        return final.replace(',', ", ")
    x=float(str1)
    #desired operation
    erro[i]=1-(e-str1)/e
```

Comment: Your error message says you are trying to convert a string `'Abs sens value'` to a `float`.

Comment: Is `'Abs sens value'` a column header?

Comment: YES! now I am ashamend, how shoul I procede to skip the header?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest :

```py
i=1
```

Change the starting index from 0 (the first line : the header cell) to 1 (the second line : the first data cell after the header).
But it will impact your `erro` variable : the `len`gth of the column `'D'` is the number of cells of content, but the number of data cells is that minus 1. But that means that your indices are shifted by one, which is a source of future errors.

So I recommend you to instead skip the first line in the loop :

```py
for cell in sheet_obj['D']:
    i=i+1
    if i == 1:
        continue  # skip the header
    str1=cell.value
```

I frequently have to work with Excel files, and I prefer to use lengthy names to not be confused, and differentiate between indices and numbers :

```py
column_cells = sheet_obj['D']
column_cells_count = len(column_cells)
header_line_number = 1
starting_scan_line_number = 1

for current_index in range(column_cells_count):
   current_line_number = current_index + 1
   if current_line_number == header_line_number:

    # skip the header row       
    continue

   else:
       ...
```

Finally, I don't think your `erro` variable has to value you meant it to have :

```py
>>> L = 4
>>> [] * L  # multiplying an empty list by an integer
[]  # gives an empty list
```

If what you want is a list of lists, do **NOT** use `[[]] * L` but use instead `[[] for _ in range(L)]` because [Lists are mutable, and multiplying a list by a number doesn't copy its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6688237/11384184).